# How to verify JWT Token in CodeIgniter 3.x for every request from Client

Tags: php, codeigniter, jwt, restful-authentication

After a long time again I am here to resolve my problem. I am much new to Codeigniter framework. I just started learning RESTful api's in CodeIgiter. Then I got to Know about that we can use JWT instead of Sessions. I am able to use the JWT and generated the token successfully. Now the problem here is, I want to verify the generated token for every request from the client.
for example,
this is the basic url or api, 
    http://localhost/codeigniter/api/

Now I want to verify something like this:

```
http://localhost/codeigniter/api?token="here the generated token will come"
```

How do I implement it, using Codeigniter 3.x

I am using codeigniter-rest server for API calls, and php-jwt to generate tokens.

Answer (score 10):

first create a helper from code https://github.com/rmcdaniel/angular-codeigniter-seed/blob/master/api/application/helpers/jwt_helper.php

then load or auto load this helper.

This will give you the token

```
helper_name::encode(data, secure_key)
```

To verify you need to use

```
helper_name::decode(token,secure_key,true)
```

it will give you data which you have encoded  or it will give you false if token is not valid.

Answer (score 2):

**Important Update:**

I updated the [repository](https://github.com/ParitoshVaidya/CodeIgniter-JWT-Sample) to **CodeIgniter 4**. Developers who want to use **CodeIgniter 3**, use following command:

```
git checkout CI3
```

**Original Answer:**

I have created a [repository](https://github.com/ParitoshVaidya/CodeIgniter-JWT-Sample) which contains this code including helper class.

Since this is a sample code, I am not expecting any `username` or `password`.

**GET auth token**

```
URL: http://host/CodeIgniter-JWT-Sample/auth/token
Method: GET
```

**Check decoded token**

```
URL: http://host/CodeIgniter-JWT-Sample/auth/token
Method: POST
Header Key: Authorization
Value: Auth token generated in GET call
```